# TypeError: response[i] is undefined in jQuery autogenerate table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the  following jquery funcion that's supposed to get a value from a text field:

My Php Code

```
function asset_status() {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT count(job_card_no) as    job_card_no,number,asset.type,asset.status,asset.id as asset_id FROM asset inner join assgnd_rsces on assgnd_rsces.name = asset.id inner join job_card on job_card.id = assgnd_rsces.job_card_id");
   $result = $query->result_array();
   echo json_encode($result); 
 }
```

ajax request

```
  asset_status_list = '';
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>operations/asset_status",
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response); // it gives following
                    //job_card_no "2" number "1" status "Active" type "Toilet"
                        for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                            asset_status_list = '<tr><td >' + response[i].job_card_no + '</td><td >' + response[i].number + '</td><td>' + response[i].type + '</td><td ><input type="hidden" name="view_more_id" class="view_more_id' + response[i].id + '" id="view_more_id" value="' + response[i].id + '"/><button id="view_more_link" class="view_more_link' + response[i].id + '"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in "></i>View More</button></td></tr>';
                            $('#asset_status_tr').append(asset_status_list);

                            $("#asset_status_tr").on("click", ".view_more_link" + response[i].id, function () {

                                var asset_id = $(".view_more_id"+response[i].id).val();
                                alert(asset_id);

                            });
                        }

                        $('#asset_table_status').DataTable({});
                    },
                    error: function (response) {

                    }
                });
```

However when I try it using the above function, I get the  following error on click of the  button.

```
TypeError: response[i] is undefined


var asset_id = $(".view_more_id"+response[i].id).val();
```

How do I solve the above error ?

Comment: What do you get in `response`? Could you post result of `console.log(response);`

Comment: @Alexander I get the  following from the  console log : job_card_no
 
 "2"
number
 
 "1"
status
 
 "Active"
type
 
 "Toilet"

Comment: Problem is with your server side code, which you have not shared with us. You are not getting json array from `<?php echo base_url(); ?>operations/asset_status` if you don't belive just write `console.log(response);` before `for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {`

Comment: Post formatted response in the **question**, not comments

Comment: could you post the screenshot of `console.log(response)` rather than just text

Comment: Are you getting single row through ajax request? Or multiple?

Comment: Post your server side code... The code which returns you the json. The code written in  `operations/asset_status`

Comment: function asset_status() {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT count(job_card_no) as job_card_no,number,asset.type,asset.status,asset.id as asset_id FROM  asset inner join assgnd_rsces on assgnd_rsces.name = asset.id inner join job_card on job_card.id = assgnd_rsces.job_card_id");
        $result = $query->result_array();
        echo json_encode($result);
    }

Comment: Problem is with using `$query->result_array();` it is not producing array in fact. What framework you are using? slim? codeiginiter or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are not getting 'json' from file that's why its length is 0 and its shown you 'undefined'.Please make sure that.

Comment: first check the length of response argument.